# A theory $T$ with only finitely many complete extensions is finitely axiomatizable iff each complete extension of $T$ is finitely axiomatizable

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic

A theory $T$ is a set of sentences. An axiomsystem $\Phi$ of $T$ has the charachteristic that $T=\{\psi:\Phi\models\psi\}$.

An expansion of $T$ is a set of sentences $T'$ which has the charachteristics that $T\subseteq T'$.

$T'$ is complete if either $\psi\in T'$ or $\neg\psi\in T'$.

(I always assume that an expansion of a theory is not necessarily complete - is this true?)

For example $T=\{\psi:\text{Groupaxioms}\models \psi\}$ is not complete because there are commutative groups and not commutative groups. The expansion $T'=\{\psi:\text{{Groupaxiomis}}\cup\text{{has one element}}\models\psi\}$ is a complete expansion.

(The last example is made by myself so maybe it is wrong)

Can someone give me a hint to solve the problem?

Let every complete expansion have a finite axiomsystem. By assumption I know that there are only finitely many complete expansions thus I look at the intersection over those axiomsystems which I assume must be an axiomsystem for the initial theory but I am not sure how to justify that.

For the other side of the proof I assume that the initial theory has a finite axiomsytem by assumption I also know that there are only finitely many complete expansions. If one of those expansions would have an infinite axiomsystem (does every theory always have an axiomsystem ? - I assume yes because the theory itself is an axiomsystem - correct me if I am wrong) then I always could add a sentence to my initial axiomsystem  which is the infitie axiomsystem but not in the inital one and create infite expansions which would be a contradiction (I always assume that simply by adding a new sentence to an axiomsystem we always create a new expansion - but is this true?) if those expansions are also complete (but I am not sure if I can assume this - i.e. need help to show that there are indeed infinte complete expansions)

Those are my ideas please help

Comment: If $T$ has only finitely many complete extensions, and each of those has a finite axiom system, which we may take to be a single axiom, then isn't the **disjunction** of those axioms an axiom for the original theory?

Comment: @bof With finite I mean finetely many complete expansions. Can you elaborate on your last comment?

Comment: $T_1,T_2,\dots,T_n$ are all the complete extensions of $T$. Each $T_i$ is finitely axiomatizable; by taking the conjunction of the axioms, $T_i$ can be axiomatized by a single sentence $\alpha_i$. Then the disjunction $\alpha_1\lor\alpha_2\lor\cdots\lor\alpha_n$ axiomatizes the original theory $T$, I think.